# Method lookup for class singleton methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I was under the impression that `obj.method` caused ruby to look for `method` thusly:

1. Look in `obj`'s singleton class.
2. Look in the modules included by `obj`'s singleton class.
3. Look in `obj`'s class.
4. Look in the modules included by `obj`'s class
5. *repeat steps 3 and 4 on the class's superclass until found*
6. If never found, call `method_missing` on the original object, `obj`.

Under this model, the **only** singleton class searched for the method is the singleton class of the original receiver, `obj`.  However, this model can't explain the fact that a subclass can access its superclass's singleton methods.  For example

```
class Foo
  def self.foo
    "foo"
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
end

Bar.foo  #=> "foo"
```

I'm confused because I believe this means that `Foo`'s singleton class is at some point searched for the method `foo`.  However, under the model above, I would expect that only `Bar`'s singleton class would be searched for `foo`.  Failing that, I would expect ruby to look in `Bar`'s class, `Class`, and then continue crawling up the superclass chain (skipping `Foo` and its singleton class completely).

So my question: what is missing from my understanding of Ruby method lookup which explains the fact that a class can access its superclass's singleton methods?

Comment: The following question has a detailed answer that might also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848667/ruby-method-lookup-path-for-an-object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When subclassing, not only is `Bar.superclass` set to `Foo`, but the same holds true for the singleton classes:

```
Bar.singleton_class.superclass == Foo.singleton_class  # => true
```

So you're not really confused. The actual lookup is:

1. Start with `obj`'s singleton class.
2. Look for instance methods down the ancestor list:

   - prepended modules (Ruby 2.0)
   - the class itself
   - included modules
3. Repeat #2 with superclass.
4. Repeat #1 but this time looking for `method_missing`

Comment: I see.  I think I always assumed that the relation was `obj.singleton_class.superclass == obj.class` instead.  Thanks for clearing this up! Also thanks for backports :)

Comment: This is a great explanation!! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty straightforward. Or not really, but anyhow:

```
The metaclass of the superclass is the superclass of the metaclass.
```

Where "metaclass" is really "singleton class". What's missing in your model is `Bar.superclass` inherits `Foo.superclass`. Plain and simple :)

Comment: I think your sentence "What's missing in your model is Bar.superclass inherits Foo.superclass" should be changed to "What's missing in your model is Bar.singleton_class inherits from Foo.singleton_class".