# Ruby method lookup path for an object

Tags: ruby

Is there a built-in Ruby method or a well-known library that returns the entire method lookup chain for an object?  Ruby looks through a confusing sequence of classes (as discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400148/method-lookup-for-class-singleton-methods-in-ruby)) for instance methods that correspond with a message and calls `method_missing` on the receiver if none of the classes respond to the message.

I put together the following code, but am sure it is missing certain cases or if it's 100% right.  Please point out any flaws and direct me to some better code if it exists.

```
def method_lookup_chain(obj, result = [obj.singleton_class])
  if obj.instance_of? Class
    return add_modules(result) if result.last == BasicObject.singleton_class
    r = result.last.superclass
    method_lookup_chain(obj, result << r)
  else
    return result + obj.class.ancestors
  end
end

def add_modules(klasses)
  r = []
  klasses.each_with_index do |k, i|
    r << k
    next if k == klasses.last
    r << (k.included_modules - klasses[i+1].included_modules)
  end
  r.flatten
end

# EXAMPLES

module ClassMethods; end
module MoreClassMethods; end
class A
  extend ClassMethods
  extend MoreClassMethods
end
p method_lookup_chain(A) # => [#<Class:A>, MoreClassMethods, ClassMethods, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>]

module InstanceMethods; end
class Object
  include InstanceMethods
end
module X; end
module Y; end
class Dog
  include X
  include Y
end
d = Dog.new
p method_lookup_chain(d) # => [#<Class:#<Dog:0x007fcf7d80dd20>>, Dog, Y, X, Object, InstanceMethods, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That other post makes it seem confusing, but it really isn't.  If you are interested in such things, you should read "Metaprogramming Ruby".  Until then, the basic rule is `one step to the right and up`:

```
          Object (superclass)
              ^
              |
          Parent class A(superclass)
              ^
              |
          Parent class B(superclass)
              ^
              |
obj  ->   object's class
```

2) Singleton classes are inserted between the obj and the object's class:

```
          Object
              ^
              |
          Parent class A(superclass)
              ^
              |
          Parent class B(superclass)
              ^
              |
          object's class(superclass)
              ^
              |
obj  ->   obj's singleton_class
```

3) Included modules are inserted immediately above the class that does the including:

```
          Object
              ^
              |
          Parent class A
              ^
              |
              Module included by Parent Class B
              ^
              |
          Parent class B
              ^
              |
          object's class
              ^
              |
obj  ->   obj's singleton_class
```

Edit:

> Please point out any flaws

```
p method_lookup_chain(Class)

--output:--
[#<Class:Class>, #<Class:Module>, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>]
```

But...

```
class Object
  def greet
    puts "Hi from an Object instance method"
  end
end

Class.greet

--output:--
Hi from an Object instance method
```

And..

```
class Class
  def greet
    puts "Hi from a Class instance method"
  end
end

Class.greet

--output:--
Hi from a Class instance method
```

The lookup path for a method called on a class actually continues past BasicObject's singleton class(`#<Class:BasicObject>`):

```
class BasicObject
  class <<self
    puts superclass
  end
end

--output:--
Class
```

The full lookup path for a method called on Class looks like this:

```
                  Basic Object                 
                      ^
                      |
                    Object
                      ^
                      |
                    Module
                      ^
                      |
                    Class
                      ^
                      |
BasicObject    BasicObject's singleton class                
  |                   ^
  |                   |
Object         Object's singleton class
  |                   ^
  |                   |
Module         Module's singleton class
  |                   ^
  |                   |
Class  --->    Class's singleton class
```

The lookup starts in Class's singleton class and then goes up the hierarchy on the right. "Metaprogramming Ruby" claims there is a unified lookup theory for all objects, but the lookup for methods called on a class does not fit the diagram in 3).

You have the same problem here:

```
class A 
end

class B < A
end

p method_lookup_chain(B)

--output:--
[#<Class:B>, #<Class:A>, #<Class:Object>, #<Class:BasicObject>]
```

It should be this:

```
                  Basic Object                 
                      ^
                      |
                    Object
                      ^
                      |
                    Module
                      ^
                      |
                    Class
                      ^
                      |
BasicObject    BasicObject's singleton class
  |                   ^
  |                   |
Object         Object's singleton class
  |                   ^
  |                   |
  A            A's singleton class
  |                   ^
  |                   |
  B.greet -->  B's singleton class
```

One thing you need to keep in mind: the lookup path of any method called on a class has to include Class somewhere because ALL classes inherit from Class.

Comment: I've read Metaprogramming Ruby and like your visualizations, but I don't think this answers my question.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent edit!  It's good to know that BasicObject.singleton_class.superclass == Class (I would prefer for BasicObject.singleton_class.superclass to equal nil, but I guess the language designers didn't want that for some reason).

Comment: IMO the [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400148/method-lookup-for-class-singleton-methods-in-ruby) does not make it confusing.  It just assumes that *ALL* method lookups (including methods called on a class) could be explained by your diagram (3).  The real confusion is that _method lookup is different for methods called on a class_.  i.e. it is Ruby that is slightly confusing :)

Comment: @Powers, Logically, Class has to be in the lookup path somewhere when you call a method on a class--because all classes inherit from Class.  I don't think Class would fit in very well at some other spot.  Also, if you look at p. 128 of "Metaprogramming Ruby", there is a diagram, and the text points out as well that Class is the parent/superclass of BasicObject's singleton class.

Comment: @ChrisRice, Fair enough. When I was putting together the diagrams, I got hoodwinked myself when I followed the diagram in 3) to draw the lookup for Class.  After awhile I realized it was incorrect, and I had to consult "Metaprogramming Ruby" to sort things out.  So I guess Powers had a point when Powers initially stated, `Ruby looks through a confusing sequence of classes`.

Comment: You misspelled `singleton_class` in 2) and 3).

Comment: @Chris, Thanks. Corrected.