# What does the mc variable name in Minitest mean?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, minitest

In the minitest.rb file is inside the module `Minitest` the variable `mc` defined. What is this variable doing? I can't derive it from the context.

Here is a part of the code:

```
##
# :include: README.rdoc

module Minitest
  VERSION = "5.8.2" # :nodoc:
  ENCS = "".respond_to? :encoding # :nodoc:

  @@installed_at_exit ||= false
  @@after_run = []
  @extensions = []

  mc = (class << self; self; end)
```

Comment: It's short for "metaclass". If `class << self; self; end` idiom says nothing to you, read a book called "Metaprogramming Ruby"

Comment: I've read a few articles in the web and played around with the irb a little bit now. I think this style is a little bit strange at the beginning. But this is probably because I haven't worked with metaprogramming a lot before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Way back in the old days, before we had the [`Object#singleton_class`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class) method, the only way to get access to the singleton class was to open up the singleton class and return `self` from the class definition expression.

Remember, a class definition expression, like all other definition expressions, evaluates to the value of the last expression evaluated inside the definition, e.g.:

```
class Foo
  42
end
# => 42
```

Remember also that inside a class definition expression, the value of the special variable `self` is the class object itself:

```
class Bar
  self
end
# => Bar
```

And last but not least, remember that `class << some_expression` opens up the singleton class of whatever object `some_expression` evaluates to.

Putting it all together:

```
class << self # Here, self is Minitest
  self        # Here, self is the singleton class of Minitest
end
```

Opens up the singleton class of `self`, which is the `Minitest` module itself, then it returns `self` from the singleton class definition, which is the class itself, ergo the singleton class of `Minitest`.

As to why the variable is named `mc`: that's short for "metaclass", which is one of the few dozen names that were proposed for what we now call the *singleton class*. ([Some of the other suggestions were eigenclass (my personal favorite), shadow class, virtual class (yuck!), ghost class, own class, …](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25348265/2988)) It's a bit of an unfortunate name, because [the term *metaclass* has a well-defined meaning](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaclass) that does not fully match what a singleton class is in Ruby.

Nowadays, we would probably just call `singleton_class` directly, or, if we want to cache it for performance reasons, do something like

```
sc = singleton_class
```

instead.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you! I've already bought the Metaprogramming Ruby Book and study it now.