# Calling gsub within method

Tags: ruby

I want to have a method called `delete_commas` that deletes commas within a string. Below is what I have:

```
def delete_commas
  gsub(',','')
end

string = "this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,"
```

I expect:

```
string.delete_commas # => "this string has alot of commas"
```

This does not work, it raises an error:

```
NoMethodError: private method 'delete_commas' called for "this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,":String
```

I could do this:

```
def delete_commas(string)
  string.gsub(',','')
end
delete_commas(string)
```

but that is not how I want to do it. Wondering if I could get some refactoring help.

I actually created a gem for this `https://github.com/txssseal/delete_commas`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: how can I create the method so when I call string.delete_commas it will delete the commas

Comment: the private method issue is due to the context in which you placed the method. When adding a method in irb it is privatized in the context of `main:Object` this means that while you added the method near the highest level (`Object`) you cannot call it directly like you tried to because it is private in this context. what you need to do is, as @shivam suggested, add the method to the `String` class.

Comment: Colton, it appears that you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how methods are invoked in Ruby. When you execute `string.delete_commas`, the method `delete_commas` is sent to the object `string`, which is called the "receiver". Ruby looks for an instance method `delete_commas` in the receiver's class (`string.class #=> String`). That's why you must define `delete_commas` in the class `String`, as shivram advises.  It's actually a little more complicated than this. See, for example, @7stud's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848667/ruby-method-lookup-path-for-an-object).

Comment: @CarySwoveland just as a note technically he is declaring an instance method accessible from `String` because he is declaring it in the context of `Object`. The problem is `irb` privatizes these methods so they can only be acessed from `main:Object`. This is evident by pasting his method into `irb` and then try `"st,r,in,g".delete_commas #=>NoMethodError` and `"st,r,in,g".send(:delete_commas) #=> "string"`

Comment: @engineersmnky, thanks. I was thinking the OP's code was inside an unspecifed class, but I see it's in `main`. Still, I suspect there may some confusion about how Ruby dispatches methods, as no mention was made of the class `Object`.

Comment: Correct, I had fundamental ideas of adding the method in the String class, but I was wondering if it was possible to do it without adding a method to the string class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define a method to String class as in `string.delete_commas`,  `delete_commas` is supposed to be a String method

```
class String
   def delete_commas
     self.gsub(',','')
   end
end

string = "this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,"

string.delete_commas
# => "this string has alot of commas"
```

Comment: yaa. I could do that, but I really do not want to create/edit a class to do all of that.  Wanted to do it within my current class.

Comment: You are not creating any new class. Your `string` is an object of String class. You are just defining a method for that class.

Comment: ya, I guess I could do that, not being a big deal

Comment: @ColtonSeal this is exactly what you requested since you said that you didn't want to pass a receiver like `delete_commas(string)` but rather wanted to call the method directly as `string.delete_commas`. Also `delete` might suggest mutation not sure if that is what you wanted or not but this method will not mutate the string but rather return a copy without commas.

Comment: true, I could rename it to replace_ commas.

Comment: @engineersmnky within the `String` class, `!` is usually used to indicate mutation, e.g. `String#delete` vs. `String#delete!`

Comment: That is much nicer looking

Comment: @stefan I understand *dangerous* methods but in many other classes `Hash`, `Array`, etc. `delete` no bang(`!`) still mutates the receiver that's why I said *"might suggest"*. Also like you stated `!` *"usually"* indicates because things like `replace` and `clear` have no bang but does mutate.

Answer (score 3):

Do this:

```
string.delete ","
```

That's it. No need to reinvent a Ruby built-in.

Answer (score 2):

As noted by @Mark Thomas, the functionality you are specifically looking for is already a part of the language, by using:

```
"this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,".delete ","
```

but if you are looking to add new functionality anyway, there are a few ways to do it.

Looking at your desired code:

```
string = "this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,"
string.delete_commas # => "this string has alot of commas"
```

You have to look at what object is receiving the message you're sending. In this case the `"this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,"` object, which is an instance of `String`. In order for that object to respond to that message, the `String` class needs to implement a method of that name, as @shivam suggests.

It is important to note that this is what is affectionately referred to as a [monkey patch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). This comes with some drawbacks, some of which are listed in the article I linked.

A safer way of attaining this goal as of Ruby 2.0 is [Refinements](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/doc/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html). By declaring a module that defines the refinement to the string class, you can choose exactly the scope at which you want to refine strings:

```
module ExtraStringUtils
  refine String do
    def delete_commas
      gsub(',','')
    end
  end
end

class MyApplication
  using ExtraStringUtils

  "this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,".delete_commas
    #=> this string has alot of commas
end

"this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,".delete_commas 
  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `delete_commas' for "this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,":String
```

In other words, you have access to your special changes to `String` wherever you are `using ExtraStringUtils`, but nowhere else.

One last way to have a similar outcome is to have your own class that implements that method and operates on a string internally:

```
class MySuperSpecialString
  def initialize string
    @string = string
  end

  def delete_commas
    @string.gsub!(',','') #gsub! because we want it to permenantly change the stored string
  end
end
```

At which point the usage would be:

```
string = MySuperSpecialString.new("this string, has, alot, of, commas,,,")
string.delete_commas # => "this string has alot of commas"
```

This approach comes with its own special set of drawbacks, the biggest of which being that it does not respond to all the methods a string would. You can use delegation to pass unknown methods to the string, but there are still some seams where it won't behave exactly like a string and it won't behave exactly as a separate class, so be aware of the return values.

Comment: depending on context this would be a great use for refinements as well. (sort of safe monkey patching)

Comment: Thatnks @engineersmnky that's a good call out. I'll add something about it.

Comment: While I am glad that you liked my suggestion my thought was if he only needed this functionality inside another class then refinements would work well e.g. `class MyApplication; using ExtraStringUtils; end` now inside of `MyApplication` every `String` would have access to `delete_commas` but not outside the class. Right now your refinement is no different than calling `gsub` inside `speak_without_extra_commas`. Mostly posted refinements comment because it is a lesser known functionality for scoping monkey patches.

Comment: @engineersmnky I updated the refinements example per your suggestions. I agree this is more clear as to the value it's providing. Thanks.